# Calling API when clicked on a Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am beginner with `React` + `Redux`.

I did a [course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/react-redux-react-router-es6/table-of-contents) on both and trying to extend the app that I created as part of Course.

In course, Cory mentioned about loading the initial data when app loads. so in our applications entry point `index.js`, we did something like

```
const store = configureStore();
store.dispatch(loadCourses());
store.dispatch(loadAuthors());
store.dispatch(loadTransactions());

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes}/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

The challenge that I see however is that we are calling `API`s even when we might not load the specific page (for example `/transactions`, but still calling `loadTransactions()`).

What are some of the approaches where we only load the data when we click on the `route` aka load a `Component`?

For example, I only call `loadTransactions()` (and save data in the `store`) when I click on `/transactions`.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I tried to work around as recommended and got the following, I want to verify if this approach is correct. Please let me know

```
class TransactionsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("component mounted");
    this.props.fetchTransactions;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Transactions</h1>
        <TransactionList transactions={this.props.transactions}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TransactionsPage.propTypes = {
  transactions: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    transactions: state.transactions
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(transactionActions, dispatch),
    fetchTransactions: dispatch(loadTransactions())
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TransactionsPage);
```

But with this I get `Warning` as

```
warning.js?8a56:36 Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

Comment: This `fetchTransactions: dispatch(loadTransactions())` should be `fetchTransactions: () => dispatch(loadTransactions())`

Answer (score 3):

I use [onEnter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback) and quite happy with it:

```
const sessionEnter = (location) => {
    let {sessionId} = location.params;
    store.dispatch(appActions.loadApp(sessionId, 'APP'))
    store.dispatch(appActions.getComboDetailsBySessionId(sessionId, 'APP'))
    setFirebaseAppListeners();
}

const routeConfig = [   
    {path: '/session/:sessionId', component: App, onEnter: sessionEnter},
    {path: '/signup', component: Signup},
    ...
];

const renderStore = () => {
    rootElement = document.getElementById('root')

    render(
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <div className="root">
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Router history={history} routes={routeConfig}/>
                </Provider>
            </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>,

        rootElement
    );
}</MuiThemeProvider>,

    rootElement
);
}
```

I prefer it to the **componentDidMount** approach when the API call is related to the route's parameters. This way the API call is made before the component is mounted which increases the chances for the data to be ready when the component will mount.

On the other hand, If I have a Weather component that only needs a state from the weather API, which will not exists anywhere else in the app, I would trigger an API call from the **componentDidMount**.

**UPDATE**

If you fix a few syntax glitches, your code will work. Working example can be found here: http://jsbin.com/sixofu/edit?js,output

Comment: This also means that the container components have the dependency on `Redux` `store` which I do not know is a good idea either.

Comment: Can you elaborate? As I see it If you have a container you are already interacting with the store through mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps.

Comment: I updated my code sample, could you please let me know if this is correct?

Comment: Are you sure this warning comes from this file? It usually means you are calling setState from the constructor or from the componentDidMount which will cause an endless loop. BTW, in this code fetchTransactions is not invoked.

Comment: @daydreamer I have added a link in my answer to a working version of your code

Answer (score 0):

Load the data inside the componentWillMount lifecycle hook in the component.

This lifecycle hook will get executed before the component renders.  You can read more here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Hope this helps.